# How to successfully download ROCR in R

Tags: r

I need to use ROCR in R, however when I try to download the file. it shows the following warning. What should I do for successfully downloading ROCR?

> download.file(ROCR)
>   Error in download.file(ROCR) : 
>     argument "destfile" is missing, with no default

Comment: Are you actually using `download.file()`? Generally to install packages you do `install.packages("ROCR")`.

Comment: But in case you really need to first download it that way, then [the docs (`?download.file`)](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/utils/html/download.file.html)) suggest that the second argument `destfile=` is required, as the error is trying to tell you.